# Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ be the two functions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$ be the two functions ?

Then, if $g\circ f:A\to C$ is onto, then what can be said about $g:B\to C$ ?

---

**My try :**

I have $g\circ f:A\to C$ here, so I can say that

" Every element $z\in C$ there exists $y\in A$ such that $g\circ f(y) = z$ "

This gives $g(f(y)) = z$

Now, this shows a form which is implying that $g$ is onto.

---

Am I right here ?

Comment: Yes, and that is all you can say.  Although the proof is somewhat too hand-wavy for me.

Comment: I have two things to say: `\to` and `\circ`.